# How can I get the color hex value of Chakra UI theme color by its name?

Tags: chakra-ui

Is there a function to get the hex value from a Chakra UI color?

Example:

```
getHexValue("gray.300") // "#CBD5E0"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that function exist! Checkout `useToken`:
https://chakra-ui.com/docs/styled-system/utility-hooks/use-token

Note that's also easy to use the generated css variable :
`var(--chakra-colors-gray-300)`

Comment: Beware of using `var(…)` directly. You'll be relying on the unchanged, default `cssVarPrefix`, which could have been set to something else in the config: https://v1.chakra-ui.com/docs/styled-system/theming/theme#config

Comment: how do we use `var(--chakra-colors-gray-300)` to get the hex value?

Comment: as above, this doesn't answer the question, this gets the CSS var, not the Hex value